# Java 8 frequency Object in array

Tags: arrays, object, dictionary, java-8, collectors

I have an `Object[] array`

I need to create map `Map<Obejct, Integer>`, where `Integer` value contains frequency of key Object in array.

How can i do it in java 8 style, using `Collectors`?

Comment: Also you need to ensure that your objects have a proper implementation of equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do (I hope I don't have any typos) :

```
Map<Object,Long> map = Stream.of(array)
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o,
                                                               Collectors.counting()));
```

This should group the elements of the array by equality and count the number of Objects in each group.

Comment: Please, explain me why Object::equals is a valid function here? I cant understand a sense.

Comment: @Sloth I was wrong. See edited answer.

Comment: `counting()` returns a Long....

Comment: Is an expression o -> o  the same as Function.identity() ?
I used Function.identity() as function and my problem solved. But o -> o also works.
EDIT: yes, its the same =)

Comment: @Sloth Yes, I didn't remember the exact syntax for Function.identity(), which is why I didn't use it in my answer.